# Android ViewFlipper content is not clickable after flip

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a problem using a ViewFlipper. On the first page I have a ListView and on the second page I have a WebView.

I can click items on the first page, flip to the second, flip again to the first page.
Now the problem appears :(
I can't click on the list-items.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the animation.

```
`android:fillAfter=false`
```

solved it.